# PowerBI Applying New Data (New Column) to Old Report - Values go blank

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerquery, relationship

I built a scorecard that dynamically compares two markets to each other - I built it with less data than I knew would go into the report because I figured I could always add more splits in later. This has been giving me difficulties as when I try to load in the new data, it is going blank.

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuHPm.png)

[After refreshing data (or changing data source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36onw.png)

Info that might help:
I have sync'ed up slicers for all but one of the filters.
The new data coming in will have different 'Period' fields than the data it is replacing.
Data is coming into Excel from external source, want it to update every week with new periods but exact same structure

I tried going in and making sure the data types were correct, tried changing the source to somewhere totally different as well - I still get blank values with the new data.

I am new to PowerBI so I am not sure why the new data is not just loading in and being captured the same way as it was the first time, with the new column available to be selected as well.

Thank you in advance for any help.